# Переполнение блока || схлопывание aside

Tags: css

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой - есть двухколоночный макет с футером прилепленным к нижней части экрана. В блоке .wrapper расположены два блока aside и .content. Блоку .wrapper высота задана двумя "высотными" свойствами height и min-height. Это сделано потому, что если не задать свойство height, то блок aside не будет заполнять всю свободную высоту экрана. Если же свойство height присутствует, то контент переполняет блок .content. Масло-масленное получилось, но надеюсь, что вы поймете)). Дополнительно прилагаю ссылку на codepen - http://codepen.io/astor/pen/pEzYOP?editors=1100

Уточняю: Если задать блоку .wrapper высоту только через свойство height, то контент в блоке .content будет вылазить за пределы футера. Если же блоку .wrapper задать height и min-height, то контент ведет себя как и нужно, но блок aside 'теряет' высоту, а должен заполнять всю доступную высоту страницы до футера.

Еще раз: нужно, чтобы и контент не вылазил за пределы футера и чтобы блок aside занимал всю доступную высоту.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background: aqua;
}
aside {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: silver;
}
section {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: gold;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <section>
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia
    voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
    modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit,
    qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  </section>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: И собственно проблема в чем? Подробнее опишите.

Comment: Описал. Посмотрите. Надеюсь стало понятней.

Comment: Сразу попутный вопрос: если "сжимать" сайт по вертикали, когда начинает текст из section "лезть"  на footer, что должно происходить? В секции должен появиться скролл или текст должен просто скрываться? Прикрепите также к вопросу, поскольку не совсем ясно.

Comment: Должен появиться скролл, но не у секции, а у всей страницы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так (использовать `dispaly: table;`):

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body, html { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 background: aqua;
 display: table;
}


aside {
 width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: silver;
    display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
}

section { 
  overflow: auto; 
  padding: 20px; 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

footer {
 height: 50px;
 background: gold; 
 margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 
 <section>
  Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
 </section>
 <aside>aside</aside>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Елена. Спасибо. Все здорово, НО, по семантике, да и по логике блок aside должен быть выше section в структуре. Может быть есть вариант это осуществить?

Comment: Ведь согласитесь, что по логике, блок с меню должен находится выше контента в структуре сайта ...

Comment: ) Пока ничего не приходит на ум.
А вообще где такое написано, что именно по семантике сайдбар должен быть выше? Просто интересно.

Comment: Если на еще меньшем разрешении вы будете использовать меди запросы и нужно будет поставить сайдбар выше, тогда да - это имеет значение, но не более.

Comment: Где написано не подскажу, просто думаю, что так правильней)

Comment: Думаю на семантику это не влияет все же. На счет правильнее ... частенько встречаю заказы, когда именно просят сайдбар располагать после основного контента (т.к. это все же второстепенный контент).

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял.

***Решение:***

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body, html { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 background: aqua;
}


aside {
 float: right;
 width: 300px;
 min-height: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 background: silver;
 overflow: auto;
}

section { 
 overflow-y: scroll; 
 padding: 20px; 
    height: 100%;
}

footer {
 height: 50px;
 background: gold; 
 margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <aside>aside</aside>
 <section>
  Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
 </section>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

ps. Я же вчера вам помог с этим, если ничего не путаю.

Comment: Не совсем то, что он хочет, по вопросу нужно, чтобы скролл появлялся не у секции, а у самой страницы.
P.S. Хотя тогда не получится сделать так, чтобы текст с секции не "лез" на footer...

Comment: "Должен появиться скролл, но не у секции, а у всей страницы. – Astor 11 минут назад" =)

Comment: Никита, да, вчера вы помогли, но проблема не ушла), Теперь пробую с другой структурой,